# using StaticResource in hijacked Style causes Crash

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I am using the materialDesign in xaml Toolkit.
I am trying to Style the TimePicker to match my theme.
Unfortunately the Timepicker has no way to set the Hint Background so I need to hijack the Style and set the Background this way.
If I do it like this:

```xml
<materialDesign:TimePicker.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignPaper">#3c3c3c</SolidColorBrush>
    <Style x:Key="MaterialDesignTimePickerTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:TimePickerTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTimePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}" />
    </Style>
</materialDesign:TimePicker.Resources>
```

The code works like it should. But as soon as I change it to this:

```xml
<materialDesign:TimePicker.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignPaper" Color="{StaticResource ThemedBackground}"/>
    <Style x:Key="MaterialDesignTimePickerTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:TimePickerTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTimePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}" />
    </Style>
</materialDesign:TimePicker.Resources>
```

I get the following error when loading the View
`Set property 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.Color' threw an exception. '#FF3C3C3C' is not a valid value for property 'Color'.`
Why does this happen and how would I be able to fix it?

Comment: What is the ThemedBackground resource, a Color or a Brush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThemedBackground` is a apparently not a `Color` but probably a `Brush`. In this case, you can try this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignPaper" Color="{Binding Color,
    Source={StaticResource ThemedBackground}}"/>
```

It should work assuming the `ThemedBackground` resource is in scope.